# Coordinates for Moving Ball Bounce Off Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm looking for this circle to rebound off the edges of the screen and bounce back into the canvas. I know you need to input coordinates just need a formula so I can understand what I'm looking at.

```
import tkinter  # Used to draw on canvas (2D plot)

class MyCircle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, dx, dy, cnum):  # "self" always 1st parameter in python methods
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = dx  # "delta-x" or "change in x" or "x velocity"
        self.dy = dy
        self.cnum = cnum   # Add circle number as parameter for log

    # delete the log files to retry
    # https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
    def logData(self):
        # Filename uses circle number.
        with open('logfile_' + str(self.cnum) + '.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write("x=" + str(self.x) +
                    " y=" + str(self.y) +
                    " dx=" + str(self.dx) +
                    " dy=" + str(self.dy) + '\n')

    def MoveIt(self, coordinates=tkinter.Canvas):
        self.x = self.x + self.dx
        self.y = self.y + self.dy

    def DrawIt(self, w):
        w.create_arc(self.x, self.y, self.x + 20, self.y + 20, start=0, extent=359,
                     fill='red')
```

Comment: Besides the ball's initial position, you're also going to need a direction vector and speed (which can be combined), plus the location of the wall. See the Wikipedia article on [deflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(physics))

Comment: The code already has the position x and y and the speed dx and dy. The dx and dy would contain the direction information. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I'm just getting into my first year of coding so lots of information to process and understand. Fascinating stuff, though.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Add a method called bounce and call it every frame (You can call it in the MoveIt method):

```
def bounce(self):
    if not 0 <= self.x <= WIDTH:
        self.dx *= -1

    if not 0 <= self.y <= HEIGHT:
        self.dy *= -1
```

We need to assume somethings here:

1. The edges (walls) has infinite mass. Means at the collisions the energy would not be passed from balls to the walls.
2. Collisions are elastic. Means the energy would not transferred to something else.

With these assumptions the collisions happens to be change in direction of speed vector of the ball.

If collision happens on left or right wall, you must change the sign (*-1) of the dx and if it happens on top or bottom walls you must change the sign of dy.

Comment: This looks like it bounces the ball whenever its x or y is in range. It's also not taking the size of the ball into consideration.

Comment: Very good point. I added `not` to if statements. And for radius you're again right. One must consider the size of the ball too. But I'll leave it for @Student to fix it...

Comment: Already fixed it. Thanks again for the assistance.